# How can I upload video via YouTube API from Amazon S3 url?

Tags: amazon-s3, youtube-api

I have an S3 Amazon account and currently all the video I upload on my site goes to there.

I have added functionality so that user may select to share their video on YouTube as well. For that I am using the YouTube API which does not support a video URL.  I was wondering if we could, somehow, provide a direct s3 link so that video gets uploaded to YouTube.

here's the flow :-

Selected video -> gets converted to mp4 format from encoding.com -> the concerted video gets uploaded to s3 amazon.

Note: I have tried downloading my video from s3 to tmp folder and then upload it, this works fine but since we are using load balancing servers it will not work with it.

Need solution asap.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Youtube as a destination within your Encoding.com job, they have already built the integration with the YouTube API.  See http://www.encoding.com/syndicate_your_videos_to_youtube for the API syntax.  It can include full meta data.  Note that you have to use Google's 2 step authentication process to create a password to use with the Encoding.com API